# Wrapper class is having problems compiling. Not sure how to resolve? Incorrect signature when adding more rows to wrapper class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I'm trying to explore my options for rotating a VF table by mimicing the following post:

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2010/09/rotating-visualforce-table.html

However near the bottom I'm having trouble getting the rows[1].addValue... to compile. They all come back with the following error:

*classes/FinancialOrdersWrapper.cls: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addValue(Decimal) from the type FinancialOrdersWrapper.RowWrapper (Line: 54, Column: 22)*

I should note that the page complies with the lines commented out and even the vf page displays as I want. However it isn't showing what I want (the final 17 fields...)

```
public with sharing class FinancialOrdersWrapper {

    public Class RowWrapper{
         public List<String> values {get; set;}
        public RowWrapper(){
           values=new List<String>();
        }
        public void addValue(String value)
        {
            values.add(value);
        }
    }
     public List<Financial_Orders_Data__c> getFinancialOrders()
    {
        if (null==fods)
        {
            fods=[SELECT Id, Name, ECD_Award_Count__c, ECD_Loss_Count__c, ECD_Losses_Dropped__c, ECD_Losses__c, ECD_Month_Win_Rate_2__c, ECD_Month_Win_Rate__c, ECD_Orders_2__c, ECD_Orders__c, ECD_Proposal_Avg__c, ECD_Proposals_2__c, ECD_Proposals__c, ECD_Signed_excluding_CO_s_2__c, ECD_Signed_excluding_CO_s__c, ECD_YTD_Win_Rate_2__c, ECD_YTD_Win_Rate__c, Month_Win_Rate__c, YTD_Win_Rate__c, First_Day_of_Month__c from Financial_Orders_Data__c order by First_Day_of_Month__c ASC];
        }

        return fods;
    }
    private List<Financial_Orders_Data__c> fods;
    private List<RowWrapper> rows;
    private RowWrapper headings;
     public RowWrapper getHeadWrap()
    {

        if (null==headings)
        {
            headings=new RowWrapper();
            for (Integer idx=1; idx<=getFinancialOrders().size(); idx++)
            {
                headings.addValue('Financial_Orders_Data__c ' + idx);
            }
        }

        return headings;
    }
     public List<RowWrapper> getRowWrappers()
    {
        if (null==rows)
        {
            rows=new List<RowWrapper>();


            for (Integer idx=0; idx<11; idx++)
            {
                rows.add(new RowWrapper());
            }

            for (Integer idx=0; idx<getFinancialOrders().size(); idx++)
            {
                rows[0].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].Name);

                //the following all break...
                /*
                rows[1].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Orders__c);
                rows[2].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Signed_excluding_CO_s__c);
                rows[3].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Losses__c);
                rows[4].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Month_Win_Rate__c);
                rows[5].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_YTD_Win_Rate__c);
                rows[6].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Award_Count__c);
                rows[7].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Loss_Count__c);
                rows[8].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].Month_Win_Rate__c);
                rows[9].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].YTD_Win_Rate__c);
                rows[10].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Orders_2__c);
                rows[11].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Signed_excluding_CO_s_2__c);
                rows[13].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Losses_Dropped__c);
                rows[14].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Month_Win_Rate_2__c);
                rows[15].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_YTD_Win_Rate_2__c);
                rows[16].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Proposals__c);
                rows[17].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Proposals_2__c);
                rows[18].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Proposal_Avg__c);
                */
            }
        }

        return rows;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? Bob's example seems to work just fine for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RowWrapper class has a method addValue() that takes String as the parameter .

Looks like in this line of code `rows[1].addValue(getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Orders__c);`

ECD_Orders__c is a field of type Decimal and hence easiest way would be to convert Decimal to String use toPlainString() method of Decimal Class .

Like below code

```
rows[1].addValue((getFinancialOrders()[idx].ECD_Orders__c).toPlainString());
```